# Xorg fails to start with Intel graphics

Tags: boot, xorg, intel-graphics

Ever since the installation of Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop today it has been refusing to start Xorg when booting on occasions. Randomly it works but about 75% of the time it either gives me a black screen with login prompt or the fail safe mode, the latter being the most common.

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to go to a terminal like screen, I managed to crack open the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file on the "faulty" boot process. Here are some lines which look interesting to me:

```
(EE) intel(0): [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:00:02.0: No such file or directory
(EE) intel(0): Failed to become DRM master.
(II) UnloadModule: "intel"
(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
Fatal server error:
no screens found
```

It is apparently loading the "vesa" driver package.

Specs of my laptop:

- CPU: Intel Core i5 2450M
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 3000
- RAM: 8 GB DDR3
- OS: Windows 8 + Ubuntu 12.10 (fully updated)

Any ideas? Any suggestions are very welcome, even if they don't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same issue, the first workaround described in [ubuntu-lightdm-black-screen](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/ubuntu-lightdm-black-screen-when-using.html) on webup8.org solved it for me. Seems to be a timing issue with LightDM and mostly SSD's.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention that I am indeed using an SSD in my laptop. I'll try the suggestion in that blog and report back :) Thanks again!

Comment: Wow, just added that single line and everything works now... Amazing how my SSD is "too fast" for Ubuntu, lol. Thank you once more :) Do you think this will be fixed with 13.04 by default?

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Tim, thanks. Maybe this will get fixed with the "upcoming" new window manager (if it's included in 13.04). We'll see :)